# How to store value in localStorage with certain format

Tags: javascript, local-storage

how can I have a localStorage value stored as

[image]

I have the value as:
ald:20221219_1833|atrv:lMh2Xiq9xN0-is9qy6DHBSpBL3ylttQQew
but its like it has an arrow to expand and shows the same value only without the {}, an also how do I insert those keys with the slash and 2dots, have the value inside "", I thought it was an object but after trying to insert the value in a variable

```js
var lsvalue = {
  /: "ald:20221219_1833|atrv:lMh2Xiq9xN0-is9qy6DHBSpBL3ylttQQew",
}

localStorage.setItem('rmStore', JSON.stringify(lsvalue))
```

but it did not work, any thoughts?

tried to code mentioned

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about. The local storage has a string and your debug line is clearly showing an object. They will not be rendered the same way. You code is writing the object into the localstorage. What exactly is your problem? Did you parse it to read the value out of localstroage? `console.log(localStorage.getItem('rmStore')); console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('rmStore')))`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  `lsvalue` is an object.  You're writing that object to `localStorage`.  And you're asking why the object in `localStorage` matches the object that you wrote to it?  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: is `/` a valid key name? i cant create an object like that to test.

Comment: did you have the change to look at the image? i need the value to be stored as in the image, that is the issue that i am facing

Comment: @JesusNavarro: Yes, we can see the image.  What isn't clear is what problem you're trying to describe.  I've updated the code in the question to a runnable code snippet, which you can see produces a syntax error and doesn't store anything in `localStorage` *at all*.  Please update the question to include a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate *specifically* what problem you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want your value to be just this string: "ald:20221219_1833|atrv:lMh2Xiq9xN0-is9qy6DHBSpBL3ylttQQew".

So, you can just assign that string alone to lsvalue, and set it to localStorage:

```
var lsvalue = "ald:20221219_1833|atrv:lMh2Xiq9xN0-is9qy6DHBSpBL3ylttQQew";
localStorage.setItem('rmStore', lsvalue);
```

Or just set that string as the value:

```
localStorage.setItem('rmStore', 'ald:20221219_1833|atrv:lMh2Xiq9xN0-is9qy6DHBSpBL3ylttQQew');
```

Both of the above solutions result in the below:
[image]

But, if you're looking to set an object to localStorage:

```
    var lsvalue = 
{
    'storedObject' : "ald:20221219_1833|atrv:lMh2Xiq9xN0-is9qy6DHBSpBL3ylttQQew"
}

localStorage.setItem('rmStore', JSON.stringify(lsvalue));
```

This setup results in the below:
[image]

Comment: I need the value of the localStorage be as in the image shown it has to be stored just like in the image, but i only have the value that goes in the "", and i dont know how to make it look and be stored as in the image

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a string, the debug tool is automatically interpreting this as an object.

```js
var lsvalue = '{"/":"ald:20221219_1833|atrv:lMh2Xiq9xN0-is9qy6DHBSpBL3ylttQQew"}';
localStorage.setItem( 'rmStore', lsvalue )
```